# How to add an additional <div> and <label> to wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, html, label

I am trying to add

```
<div class="menu-toggle">
<label for="checkbox" id="checkboxLabel">Menu</label></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```

to a wordpress menu. I am using the the custom menu widget, but have no idea how to add this piece of code above

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
```

The reason why I would like to do this is because I have some css which allows me to toggle the menu on and off on smaller screen sizes. When I add the code above in the correct place using google chrome inspector it works perfectly, I am now stuck trying to implement this 'live'. I know it will be editing one of the wordpress .php files, but that is not my strong point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ask it on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Tip: research for [Custom Walker](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=custom%20walker%20is%3aa) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your theme but there might be a chance it's located inside header.php. Go to Appearance > Editor and select header.php. Do a search for the menu.

Make sure you have closing div tags like this.

```
<div class="menu-toggle">
  <label for="checkbox" id="checkboxLabel">Menu</label></div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```